# Python - Change unknown variable of type tuple outside function without global nor return

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

It's a very specific question for a very specific situation.
My function is supposed to return None and I don't know the name of the variable that I need to change before hand. All I know is that the function is supposed to change the variable.

```
def next(list):
    temporary = [x for x in list]
    temporary.append(temporary[-1] + 1)
    ??? = temporary
    return None
"""
>>>secrettuple = (2, 3, 4, 5)
>>>next(secrettuple)
>>>secrettuple
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
"""
```

Sorry if this is too similar to another article on the website, I've been browsing for 2 hours and couldn't find an answer to my problem, maybe I wasn't using the right search terms.

Comment: What you're asking does not appear to be possible (without using either `global` or `return`). If you passed a list to your function, it would be easy: you could just modify the list. But tuples are unmodifiable.

Comment: @khelwood funny that you say that because I actually found a way to do it (see answer below). I was surprised that i worked, But it worked and it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I said "If you passed a list to your function, it would be easy: you could just modify the list." You did exactly what I said.

Comment: @khelwood Still, I started out with a tupple and a list returned with the element I wanted to add, other people seem to receive errors when doing this, so I don't think my post will be of any use to anyone. I'm going to delete it
Edit: Never mind that, I can't delete it...

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are dealing with a `list` object (which is mutable):

```
def next(lst, some_lst):
    temporary = [x for x in lst]
    temporary.append(temporary[-1] + 1)
    some_lst[:] = temporary

next(secrettuple, real_list)
```

You don't need to `return None` since by default a function will return `None`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that I don't need to return None

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to do it, it was easier than I tought

```
def next(list):
    temporary = [x for x in list]
    list.append(temporary[-1] + 1)
```

This will add an element to both tuples and lists, this is all I needed to be able to do

Edit: I don't know why this worked for me, but other people seem to get errors when doing this

Comment: If I run this code with the data you gave in the question I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`. And of course it's bad style to reuse the names of the built-ins [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

Comment: @Matthias weird, no idea why it worked for me, still, my problem is solved, I'll just close this since no one seems to think this is usefull
Edit: Never mind that, I can't delete it when there are answers